# Old magnetostatics problem - new doubt

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose that the magnetic field in some region has the form $\mathbf{B} = kz \mathbf{\hat{x}}$ (where $k$ is a constant). Find the force on a square loop (side $a$), lying in the $yz$ plane and centered at the origin, if it carries a current $I$, flowing counterclockwise, when you look down the $x$ axis.

---

The forces on the part of the wire that is parallel to the $z$ axis would be null, since we would integrate an odd function over a symmetric interval.

On the other hand, for the part of the wire located at $z = -a/2$ we would have the line element as $d\mathrm{\mathbf{l}} = dy \mathbf{\hat{y}}$, since the current goes up, parallel to the $y$ axis, from $y = -a/2$ to $y = a/2$. The integral giving the force would yield

$$
\mathbf{F_1} = I \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} dy \; \mathbf{\hat{y}} \; \times \; k(-a/2) \; \mathbf{\hat{x}} = \frac{Ika^2}{2} \mathbf{\hat{z}}.
$$

Furthermore, for the part of the wire located at $z = a/2$, the line element is $d\mathrm{\mathbf{l}} = dy (-\mathbf{\hat{y}})$, since the current goes down the wire, parallel to the $y$ axis, from $y = a/2$ to $y = -a/2$. Now, on this segment, the force is

$$
\mathbf{F_2} = I \int_{a/2}^{-a/2} dy \; (-\mathbf{\hat{y}}) \; \times \; k(a/2) \; \mathbf{\hat{x}} = -\frac{Ika^2}{2} \mathbf{\hat{z}}.
$$

The sum of all forces, thus, would be null. But everybody seem to agree that the answer is actually $Ika^2$. What am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: I think you've double counted your negatives by taking the path backwards and making the y unit vector negative but I haven't actually written this out yet to check.

Comment: @Triatticus 

Well, I actually **did** take the line element in the $-\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ direction and also have integrated in the opposite direction. But I thought that I must do it, since I'm going "down" a line parallel to the $y$ axis from $y = a/2$ to $y = -a/2$.

Comment: @Triatticus 

On the other hand, by the "right hand rule", the force on any of the wires (that are parallel to the $y$ axis) should point in the $+\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ direction. Therefore, something is wrong. You seem to be right about double counting negative signs, but I can't understand why I shouldn't have them both in the line element and in the path.

Comment: Yes as you saw it's specifically what the answer is you've seen below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake that you have made is related to your choice of $d\mathrm{\mathbf{l}}$ in the second integral.
Noting that the sign of $dy$ is determined by the limits of integration, $d\mathrm{\mathbf{l}} = dy\, \mathbf{\hat{y}}$ is true for both integrals.

What you have decided is that you want to link the limits of integration to the direction of the current $I$.

In the first integral you go from position $-a/2\,\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ to position $+a/2\,\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ and using $d\mathrm{\mathbf{l}} = dy\, \mathbf{\hat{y}}$ the $dy$ increment is going to be positive, ie $d\mathrm{\mathbf{l}}$ will be in the $+\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ direction.

In the second integral you go from position $+a/2\,\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ to position $-a/2\,\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ and using $d\mathrm{\mathbf{l}} = dy\, \mathbf{\hat{y}}$ the $dy$ increment is going to be negative, ie $d\mathrm{\mathbf{l}}$ will automatically be in the $-\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ direction so you do not need to add the minus sign in the term $(-\mathbf{\hat{y}})$.

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote you, but I don't have enough "reputation" yet, hehe. ^^

Comment: You don't really have to upvote, your accepting of the answer awards the points. Anyone else who upvotes will add more points to it then :)